# PHP - Client Selects X Quantity - Want To Grab X Quantity From Stock & Email All

Tags: php, foreach, blockchain, paypal-ipn

So I've been trying with this for a while now and can't seem to find the solution.

I have a website, selling digital good.

When the client checks out, it asks for what quantity.

I want to make it so when they type in for example, quantity 5, I want it to grab 5 stocks from the database and send all to their email.

I need to make it loop through and grab x quantity from a stock table where the assignedProduct is the product ID.

**Currently, my code only getting the number of quantity and not getting different rows from my stock database. How do I make it loop the stock?**

[image: Currently showing this]

**My current code is (using blockchain payment processor):**

```
<?php

    $smtp_btc = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `productitems` WHERE `avaliable` = :avaliable AND `assignedProduct` = :assignedProduct');
    $smtp_btc->execute(array(':avaliable' => '0', ':assignedProduct' => $product_id));
    $query = $smtp_btc->fetchAll();

    // Select all from stock where avaliable = true and assignedProduct is the main productID
    // Then make it 

    // Foreach loop here
    $i = 0;
    $maxiterations = $quantity - 1;
    $message = '';

    foreach($query as $row_product) {
        while($i <= $maxiterations) {
            $i++;
            $product_link_stock = $row_product['code'];
            $stock_id_stock = $row_product['id'];

            $message = "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Email/Username:Pass(".$i."):</strong> </td><td>$product_link_stock</td></tr>";
            echo $message.'<br>';
        }
    }


?>
```

Comment: .....and what exactly in all that code is not working yet? What have you tried to debug the problem?And how is all that related to a blockchain or PayPal?

Comment: @NicoHaase I now have sorted the code out. I just need to make it grab different rows from the database.

Comment: Sounds fine. What's your question about this? "How do I make loop" sounds pretty vague

Comment: @NicoHaase My question is how do i make it grab different stocks from the database. I have made it only show for example 3 lines when 3 for quantity is put. But it's showing the same rows from the database 3 times. Look at the picture above.

Answer (score 0):

You have two loops, a foreach loop and a while loop. The data is being set once in the outer foreach loop, apparently to the first line of the query result or there may only be one result.

And then you're just printing the same data 3 times from the while loop.

Going up to the top:

`$query = $smtp_btc->fetchAll();`

What is the actual contents of $query here? Is it just 1 record?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I need to do my query inside of my while loop so it can change the row it selects for each quantity.

**This is my working code:**

```
            $i = 1;
            $maxiterations = $quantity;

            while($i <= $maxiterations) {
                $smtp_btc = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `productitems` WHERE `avaliable` = :avaliable AND `assignedProduct` = :assignedProduct LIMIT $maxiterations");
                $smtp_btc->execute(array(':avaliable' => '0', ':assignedProduct' => $product_id));
                $query = $smtp_btc->fetchAll();

                foreach($query as $row_product) {
                    $product_link_stock = $row_product['code'];
                    $stock_id_stock = $row_product['id'];

                    $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Email/Username:Pass(".$i."):</strong> </td><td>$product_link_stock</td></tr>";
                    // Update stock foreach stock product they require (quantity depends on this)
                    $updateStock = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE `productitems` SET `avaliable` = :avaliable WHERE `id` = :id');
                    $updateStock->execute(array(':avaliable' => '1', ':id' => $stock_id_stock));
                    $i++;
                }
                $i++;
            }
```